# Divergence of Cross Products of vectors in Rn.

Tags: vector-spaces, curl, divergence-theorem

Is there some formula for the Divergence of cross Product of (n-1) vectors in $\mathbb{R}_n$.
I happen to know of such a formula for $\mathbb{R}_3$, so wanted to know. Pls add/link a proof as well.

Here is the three dimensional case.
$\vec{\nabla} \cdot\left ( \vec{A}\times\vec{B} \right )=\vec{B}\cdot\left ( \nabla \times\vec{A} \right )-\vec{A}\cdot\left ( \nabla \times\vec{B} \right )$

Comment: In Einstein notation (where the summation symbols are suppressed), we may rewrite $\nabla\cdot(A\times B)$ as the expression $\varepsilon^{ijk}\partial_i(a_jb_k)$, where $\varepsilon$ is the Levi-Civita symbol. Also note $\partial_i$ is short for the partial derivative with respect to the $i$th coordinate.

Comment: Then using the fact $\varepsilon$ is alternating (which means you can swap indices, as long as you introduce a $-$ sign each time you do), and the product rule for $\partial_i$, we get $$ \varepsilon^{ijk}\partial_i(a_jb_k)=(\varepsilon^{ijk}\partial_i a_j)b_k+a_j(\varepsilon^{ijk}\partial_ib_k)=b_i(\varepsilon^{ijk}\partial_j a_k)-a_i(\varepsilon^{ijk}\partial_jb_k). $$ This latter expression is one other than $B\cdot(\nabla\times A)-A\cdot(\nabla\times B)$. You can decide how to generalize